# NullPointerException in Flink custom SourceFunction

Tags: scala, apache-flink

I wanted to create a SourceFunction which reads a http stream. 
I used ScalaJ which does what I want (it splits the incoming text by \n-s).
Obviously the code works outside Flink, but I get a NullPointerExcetion every time I start it as a Flink job (sometimes immediately sometimes after 1-2 seconds after it transmitted 1-2 elements). It kind of looks like the Http object has some problems.

```
import org.apache.flink.streaming.api.functions.source.SourceFunction

import scala.io.Source.fromInputStream
import scalaj.http._

class HttpSource(url: String) extends SourceFunction[String] {

  @volatile var isRunning = true
  override def cancel(): Unit = isRunning = false

  override def run(ctx: SourceFunction.SourceContext[String]): Unit =
    httpStream(ctx.collect)

  private def httpStream(f: String => Unit) = {
    val request = Http(url)
    request
      .execute { inputStream =>
        fromInputStream(inputStream)
          .getLines()
          .takeWhile(_ => isRunning)
          .foreach(f)
      }
  }
}
```

Here's the exception I usually get: 
(Sometimes it's a bit different, for example I tried to make the request value transient, then it's already null when it tries to refer to request)

```
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at java.io.Reader.<init>(Reader.java:78)
    at java.io.InputStreamReader.<init>(InputStreamReader.java:129)
    at scala.io.BufferedSource.reader(BufferedSource.scala:24)
    at scala.io.BufferedSource.bufferedReader(BufferedSource.scala:25)
    at scala.io.BufferedSource.scala$io$BufferedSource$$charReader$lzycompute(BufferedSource.scala:35)
    at scala.io.BufferedSource.scala$io$BufferedSource$$charReader(BufferedSource.scala:33)
    at scala.io.BufferedSource.scala$io$BufferedSource$$decachedReader(BufferedSource.scala:62)
    at scala.io.BufferedSource$BufferedLineIterator.<init>(BufferedSource.scala:67)
    at scala.io.BufferedSource.getLines(BufferedSource.scala:86)
    at flinkextension.HttpSource$$anonfun$httpStream$1.apply(HttpSource.scala:21)
    at flinkextension.HttpSource$$anonfun$httpStream$1.apply(HttpSource.scala:19)
    at scalaj.http.HttpRequest$$anonfun$execute$1.apply(Http.scala:323)
    at scalaj.http.HttpRequest$$anonfun$execute$1.apply(Http.scala:323)
    at scalaj.http.HttpRequest$$anonfun$toResponse$3.apply(Http.scala:388)
    at scalaj.http.HttpRequest$$anonfun$toResponse$3.apply(Http.scala:380)
    at scala.Option.getOrElse(Option.scala:121)
    at scalaj.http.HttpRequest.toResponse(Http.scala:380)
    at scalaj.http.HttpRequest.scalaj$http$HttpRequest$$doConnection(Http.scala:360)
    at scalaj.http.HttpRequest.exec(Http.scala:335)
    at scalaj.http.HttpRequest.execute(Http.scala:323)
    at flinkextension.HttpSource.httpStream(HttpSource.scala:19)
    at flinkextension.HttpSource.run(HttpSource.scala:14)
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.api.operators.StreamSource.run(StreamSource.java:87)
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.api.operators.StreamSource.run(StreamSource.java:55)
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.runtime.tasks.SourceStreamTask.run(SourceStreamTask.java:95)
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.runtime.tasks.StreamTask.invoke(StreamTask.java:263)
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.taskmanager.Task.run(Task.java:702)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

Everything else seems to be working fine, when I don't use a http request, but something else like file read with the same InputStream type, just a plain while loop with strings or even when I use single http requests, which aren't streaming.

I feel like I'm missing some theoretical background, maybe flink does something in the background which destroys the Http object or the InputStream, but I didn't find anything in the documentation.

UPDATE #1:

If I put a null check into the lambda, the job usually exits immediately, sometimes processes a few elements, sometimes timeouts after hanging for a minute. Here's this version of the httpStream function:

```
  private def httpStream(f: String => Unit) = {
    val request = Http(url)
    request
      .execute { inputStream =>
        if (inputStream == null) println("null inputstream")
        else {
          println("not null inputstream")
          fromInputStream(inputStream)
            .getLines()
            .takeWhile(_ => isRunning)
            .foreach(f)
        }
      }
  }
```

UPDATE #2:

The code actually works in distributed mode and with StreamExecutionEnvironment.createLocalEnvironment()

I only experience the issue if I use start-local.sh and submit the jar to it.

Comment: My first guess would be that it is something along the lines of "method1 of classA is called before classA.myVar is initialized". If I understand the error message correctly, the error is in the "fromInputStream().getLines...foreach(f)". I would first try breaking up that into individual variables so you can see what is returned after each method is called and see which one is throwing the nullPointerException. So like "varA = fromInputStream(inputStream); varB = varA.getLines; etc...".

Comment: The problem is that the inputStream is already null.
I just tried it with
    val env = StreamExecutionEnvironment.createLocalEnvironment()
instead of 
   val env = StreamExecutionEnvironment.getExecutionEnvironment() + start-local.sh
and it works with that.

Comment: Now I tried it with distributed mode, and it works as well.

So for some reason it has some problems with start-local.sh mode, otherwise it's working.

Comment: Ok, guessing it had to do with the source not being local but the environment was set to that (just spitballing). But either way, glad it is working!